# create an expandable grid view in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to create an expandable grid view in Yii2 but I have some problems.
I get this warning:

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\DataColumn.php at line 129
   $provider = $this->grid->dataProvider;

    if ($this->label === null) {
        if ($provider instanceof ActiveDataProvider && $provider->query instanceof ActiveQueryInterface) {
            /* @var $model Model */
            $model = new $provider->query->modelClass;
            $label = $model->getAttributeLabel($this->attribute);
        } else {
            $models = $provider->getModels();
129         if (($model = reset($models)) instanceof Model) {
                /* @var $model Model */
                $label = $model->getAttributeLabel($this->attribute);
            } else {
                $label = Inflector::camel2words($this->attribute);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $label = $this->label;
    }
```

This is my search model code:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\base\Model;

use app\models\Articles;
 /**
* 
*/
class ArticlesSearch extends Model
{
    /* your calculated attribute */
    public $article_num;
    public $title;
    public $jour_id;


    /* setup rules */
    public function rules() {
       return [
        /* your other rules */
        [['title'], 'safe']
       ];
    }


    public function search($params) {
        $query = Articles::find()->select('*')
                                ->where(['`journal_id`'=>$this->jour_id]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);


        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->orderBy('`articles`.`publication_date` ASC ');
        $query->andWhere(['LIKE','title',$this->title]);

       // $query->orFilterWhere(['like', '`publishers`.`name`', $this->name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
    public function getCount() 
    {

    }
    public function getModels() 
    {

    }
}
```

I added two last methods to my class to bypass the following error:

```
Calling unknown method: app\models\ArticlesSearch::getCount()

Calling unknown method: app\models\ArticlesSearch::getModels()
```

I don't know why I need this two methods in my class. I have written two other search models and I didn't put these methods there and they work fine!!!

Controller code:

```
$dataProvider=new ArticlesSearch();
$dataProvider->jour_id=$param['journalID'];
$searchModel= $dataProvider->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
return $this->render('index', [  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```

View code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' =>$searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                            [
                                'class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
                                'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
                                //'width'=>'36px',
                                'header'=>'',
                                'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style']
                            ],
                            [
                                'class'=>'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                                'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
                            ],
                            [
                                'class'=>'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                                //'width'=>'50px',
                                'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                                },
                                'detail'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                   // return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expand-row-details', ['model'=>$articles]);
                                },
                                'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'] 
                                //'disabled'=>true,
                                //'detailUrl'=>Url::to(['/site/test-expand'])
                            ],
                            [
                                'attribute'=>'Title',
                                //'value' => $model->title,
                               // 'width'=>'410px',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]);
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it may be because your query is not returning any results. I had a similar problem myself once. Do you have an IDE that you can debug through? Or are you able to see the Yii2 debug toolbar? If so, look at the database queries section. find the query that is generating your results; it should have the SELECT WHERE `journal_id` bit in it. Find that query and run it through the sql statement in phpmyadmin. That will tell you if your query is generating any results or not. That will be a start!

Comment: Oh, and in your controller, where is the variable $param coming from? Can you post the whole action from the controller?

Comment: Thanks Joes, I found the query and as you said there was a problem with it  when I executed in phpMyadmin, there was no record for that journal_id!!! after I fixed it still I had the same problem then I sent $dataProvider to widget as 'filterModel' and $searchModel as 'dataProvider' !! All the errors has gone now and it works properly!! But still I can't understand why $searchModle contain dataProvider content and $dataProvider has searchModle values!!!! So confusing!!!!!

Comment: I've amended my answer, I hope this helps. You shouldn't need to be adding in extra methods, or swapping dataProviders for searchModels! I've added some comments to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this amended code and see if it works. I've added some comments to explain what is going on.

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Articles;

/**
** firstly, your search model needs to extend your original class, that was you have access to all the original attributes of your model, without having to declare them again.
**/
class ArticlesSearch extends Articles
{
    //If your original model already has these properties, you don't need to declare them again.
    public $article_num;
    public $title;
    public $jour_id;


/* Here you should declare rules for ALL the attributes that you want to use in search */
public function rules() {
   return [
    /* your other rules */
    [['title', 'jour_id', 'article_num'], 'safe']
   ];
}


public function search($params) {
    //Start by defining your basic search function
    $query = Articles::find();

    //Add in the dataProvider
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    //Start building the query that will be used to retrieve results
    $query->where(['jour_id' => $this->jour_id]);

    //Try to load the $params and validate them. If this fails, just return the dataProvider and do nothing else
    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    //If we're still in the method, carry on building the query
    $query->orderBy('`articles`.`publication_date` ASC ');

    //andFilterWhere() is better because it ignores empty values
    $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE','title',$this->title]);

    return $dataProvider;
    }
    //Finally, remove the two extras functions you put in. If everything is working, you shouldn't need them.
}
```

Next, in your controller, use this code;

```
//Here you are telling Yii what model you want to use for searching, and for generating the form for the grid search.
$searchModel = new ArticlesSearch();

//I'm not sure where this $param is coming from.
$dataProvider->jour_id=$param['journalID'];

//Now you are actually setting up the dataProvider for the grid view. Notice that your $searchModel->search() method always returns a dataProvider, so this is the correct way to do it. Yii::$app->request->queryParams is loading the parameters that the search method will use for it's parameters.
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
return $this->render('index', ['searchModel' => $searchModel, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```

Now you should be able to use the grid widget as normal, use the dataProvider and searchModel for your dataProvider and filterModel respectively, but don't mix them up!

Comment: Thanks Joe, I changed the rules but still getting the same error!

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe, It works just fine! But I just modified controller code and  replaced $dataProvider->jour_id=$param['journalID']; with $searchModel->jour_id=$param['journalID']; :)